# Do files compiled for armeabi have some problems with armeabi-v7a

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I am using a library in my project to play videos. The library comes up with a `demo project`. The demo project is working fine.

The library has few `.Jar` files, some library classes, and a lot of `.so` files. The demo project  put the `Jar` files in `lib` folder and `.so` files in `armeabi` and `x86` folder.

I did the same, but it start giving me following error message.

> UnsatisfiedLinkError (Can't find dependent libraries)

Then i put these `.so` files in `armeabi-v7a` folder, and the error is gone.

but still its not working completely fine.

Its not giving me any error message, but still its also not initializing the class that is available in the `Decompiled.class` file. The same class is initializing successfully in `demo` project. I found out this problem after debugging both projects.

I have checked each and everything, the only difference i can see in demo and my project is `armeabi-v7a` and `armeabi`.

So do files compiled for armeabi have some problems with armeabi-v7a, or it can be some other problem.

Answer (score 1):

arm-eabi vs armeabi-v7a should not be the problem. At the low level, armeabi-v7a is compatible with armeabi, **but not vice versa**.

Can you add more debug and give more info?

Comment: Thanks, so i think the `.so` files are compiled for `armeabi`, and thats why they are not working in the `armeabi-v7a` project. 
Can you please confirm me that which version of `Gradle` supports `armeabi` ?

Comment: as  right now i am using `Gradle 2.1.2` and  `compileSdkVersion 24
 buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"` and in DEMO project i am using `:gradle:1.2.3`
`

Comment: The so files that are armeabi should work in the armeabi-v7a project, just not vice versa. Your Gradle version should support both. What version of Android Studio (or Eclipse) are you using?

Comment: I am using Android Studio 2.1.2